# Pass parameter to controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, controller, jwt

I have some app with JWT authentication. And currently, I have such controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("users")
public class UserController {
    @PostMapping(value = "{userId}/rate/inc")
    public Double incRate(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        return service.incUserRate(userId);
    }
}
```

But, I want to get user by the token in the filter and pass it as a method's param. For example:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/rate/inc")
public Double incRate(User user) {
    returnservice.incUserRate(user);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement [argument resolver](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) and inject into your controller everything you need.

By default Spring allowes you to inject Principal object that by default contains users email (it is default realization in Spring Security). But you can implement injection of your business login users account by implementing `Interface HandlerMethodArgumentResolver<User>`.

I advice you to create an annotation like `@AuthorizedUser` in make mark your `User` param with this annotation. And according to this annotation presence in controller method, inject your user via `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

```
@Component
public class UserArgumentHandlerResovler implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.isAnnotationPresent(AuthorizedUser.class);
    }

    public Object   resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) { 
         Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
         String email = (String) auth.getPrincipal(); // <- it is a pseudocode, check your Authentication implementation to get email for example.
         return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the AuthorizedUser class have? Could you post it?

Comment: `AuthorizedUser` is just a marker annotation, you may omit it and use a different approach to recognize your specific user.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Spring Security, you can resolve the current user and then have it provided to your controller method. However – if I'm not mistaken – you must declare it as [Principal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/rate/inc")
public Double incRate(Principal principal) {
    returnservice.incUserRate((User)principal);
}
```

A more extensive example can be found at [Baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security).